# Prompting user input with Scanner until user terminates with <ctrl D>

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, split

I am writing a small Java Application called NameList.java. It should prompts for a character  to split a string by. 
It should then prompt for a list of names, one per line until the user terminates. for now the name will a simple one of length 2 like this 
**"first-name family name"**.

After reading each name, the program should present the name as "surname, given-name" (e.g., "Smith, John"). It should report that the person goes to Lecture Hall A if their surname comes before the split letter or starts with it, or that they go to Lecture Hall B otherwise.

I don't know why when I run my code the I am not getting the continuous prompting ? Any resaon why? Thank you all for your time and response.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Namelist {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Split String ...");
        char  splitter = in.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        String checker;

        while(in.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Enter a name to check ...");
            String s = in.next();
            String[] tokens = s.split(" ");

            if (tokens[0].contains(Character.toString(splitter).toLowerCase())
                || tokens[1].toLowerCase().charAt(0)== splitter) {

                System.out.printf("%s, %s : Lecture Room A." ,tokens[1],tokens[0]);
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%s, %s : Lecture Room B.",tokens[1],tokens[0]);
            }

            in.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What does `Scanner#next()` do? What does `Scanner#close()` do?

Comment: the next() method is to return the next token  and the close() is to close the scanner to prevent resource leak as my eclispe keeps complaining about it. I have never  used this way of prompting for user input before but i just wanted to know how for my test

Comment: And what is the definition of a token? And what does `!in.hasNext()` mean?

Comment: Tokens are units of a Java program eg literal tokens containing characters of int,string etc? ohh I made a mistake in the question it is supposed to be in.hasNext() to check if there are anymore other tokens present.

Comment: I think you should start by reading the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: In particular for your case, inspect the "Throws" section of the hasNext method description.

Comment: When eclipse issues a warning saying resource leaks is it the same as memory leaks